# Is there a script or sheets function to find all particular word occurences in column x and add a corresponding value in column y?

Tags: excel, csv, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I have a dataset of hate speech identification and it contains label and tweet as its columns. I want to label my tweets with either 0 or 1 indicating "Normal" and "Hate/Offensive" respectively. I have a specified sets of keywords that define hate speech and hence I can replace it with "1's". The dataset is too big (17000+ tweets) and can't individually type and change them. Is there a way so that I can find all hate speech keywords in the tweet column and replace the label column with "1's"?

Comment: Check [Search](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/search-searchb-functions-9ab04538-0e55-4719-a72e-b6f54513b495). It may help

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula on `Y2`:

#### Formula:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(REGEXMATCH(FILTER(X2:X, X2:X <> ""), CONCATENATE("(?i)", JOIN("|", FILTER(W2:W, W2:W <> "")))), 1, 0))`

#### Sample Output:

[image: output]

#### Behaviour:

- Given that the list of hate speech words are in Column `W`, Tweets `X` and Labels `Y`
- This is case insensitive so it won't matter if it does not match exactly, as long as same letters were used.

#### Limitations:

- As long as `X` contains a text from `W`, `Y` will be 1. Bad example is "Arse" vs "parse"

#### EDIT:

- To fix this limitation, I will provide a very long formula that combines multiple condition to fix the issues. If it works on you then that's good.

#### Formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
IF(REGEXMATCH(FILTER(X2:X, X2:X <> ""), CONCATENATE("(?i)[A-z]", JOIN("[A-z]|[A-z]", FILTER(W2:W, W2:W <> "")), "[^A-z]")), 0, 
IF(REGEXMATCH(FILTER(X2:X, X2:X <> ""),
CONCATENATE("(?i)\S", JOIN("\S|\S", FILTER(W2:W, W2:W <> "")), "\S|", 
CONCATENATE("^", JOIN("$|^", FILTER(W2:W, W2:W <> "")), "$|"), 
CONCATENATE("[^[:alpha:][:punct:]]", JOIN("[^[:alpha:][:punct:]]|[^[:alpha:][:punct:]]", FILTER(W2:W, W2:W <> "")), "[^[:alpha:][:punct:]]|"), 
CONCATENATE("[^[:alpha:][:punct:]]?", JOIN("[^[:alpha:][:punct:]]|[^[:alpha:][:punct:]]?", FILTER(W2:W, W2:W <> "")), "[^[:alpha:][:punct:]]|"), 
CONCATENATE("[^[:alpha:][:punct:]]", JOIN("[^[:alpha:][:punct:]]?|[^[:alpha:][:punct:]]", FILTER(W2:W, W2:W <> "")), "[^[:alpha:][:punct:]]?"))), 1, 0)))
```

#### Behaviour:

- Basically, what the long formula does is that if the word/words were found, it checks if what are the characters beside it. If they are nothing, space, number and punctuation, then count as 1. If those were letters `e.g. arse vs sparse, parse, arsenal`, then it will count as 0.

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Reference:

- [Syntax for Regular Expressions](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1371415?hl=en)